# SQL data not retrieved in Unicode Hindi

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, unicode-string

I am developing a web app in ASP.NET with C#. I am saving data in  SQL tables as Unicode character as given by Google Transliteration. I am supposed to use Hindi. I have no issues regarding adding data. But when I use "SELECT" statements, no data is retrieved from the database tables in any case.

My Query is as follows:

```
SELECT        uid, family_head, member_name, house_no, address, f_h_name, gender, caste, dob, occupation, literacy, end_date
FROM            family
WHERE        (member_name = 'समर्थ अग्रवाल')
```

It return null.

Comment: Make sure that DB you are using is UTF-8 encoded so that it will store the characters from other languages too.

Comment: It works perfect if I don't use the WHERE clause. In that case all rows are returned.
My DB is MS SQL DB 2008, and it is storing all the data without issues.

Comment: is the data type  for member_name nvarchar ?

Comment: If you'd passed the value to search for as a *parameter*, rather than inserting it into the query as a string literal, you wouldn't have this issue - and it's a good practice to get into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the string to start with `N` to signify it is a Unicode string:

```
SELECT        uid, family_head, member_name, house_no, address, f_h_name, gender, caste, dob, occupation, literacy, end_date
FROM            family
WHERE        (member_name = N'समर्थ अग्रवाल')
```

Otherwise, the string will not be a Unicode string and the query will return no results.

See [Constants (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) on MSDN:

> Unicode strings
>
> Unicode strings have a format similar to character strings but are preceded by an N identifier (N stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard). The N prefix must be uppercase. For example, 'Michél' is a character constant while N'Michél' is a Unicode constant. Unicode constants are interpreted as Unicode data, and are not evaluated by using a code page.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually, I tried putting an 'n' there but not an 'N'.

Comment: @Samarth - It has to be an upper case `N`.

Comment: I am also facing above problem. I have tried above solution but its not working. It returns null.

Comment: @AtulPhadtare - Well, I don't know your particular circumstances. The OP did say that the columns are `NVARCHAR` in the database - are yours? Are you certain the string you are looking for exists in the column being searched?

Comment: @Oded-I m using nvarchar(max). My query is like this: select * from tbl_hindi where student=N'समर्थ'.

Comment: @Atul - Chances are that the table doesn't contain that data.

Comment: @Oded- whwn i am trying  'select * from tbl_hindi' then it shows all records correctly but when i am using 'where' then its not working...

Comment: @Atul - If your `WHERE` clause is for items that don't exist in the database, it will return nothing.

Comment: @Oded How do I add `N` with a parameter in my Store Procedure? I tried using `'N'+@myAddress` but its not working.